# Get names of all the directories with similar naming pattern in Perl

Tags: perl, unix

I have a directory "logs" which contains sub-directories as "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3".

I want to write a perl code that search all the sub directories with name pattern as "A", i.e. all the directories names starting from character A.

Please help me.

Comment: Does it need to recurse?

Comment: @Barmar Sounds like it if he is talking about sub directories.

Comment: @squiguy I know, but does he need to find subdirectories of subdirectories, and subdirectories of subdirectories of subdirectories?

Comment: @Barmer I am just trying to find sub directories. There is not further sub directories in A1, A2, B1, B2 etc..  Indeed, A1, A2, A3, B1, B2 etc has many files inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Perl core module [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

#Find in 'logs' directory, assume the script is executed at this folder level

find(\&wanted, 'logs');

sub wanted { 
    #Subroutine called for every file / folder founded ($_ has the name of the current)
    if(-d and /^A/ ) {
       print $_, "\n"; 
    }
}
```

**Update:**
If you want to parametrize the prefix, you can do this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $prefix = 'B';

find(\&wanted, 'logs');
sub wanted { 
    if(-d and /^$prefix/ ) {
       print $_, "\n"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. This is actually working. But I see it becomes static. how can we make A as dynamic. Means i want to use a variable value in place of A. Can we use something like if(-d and /^$val/ ) {

Answer (score 0):

`File::Find` is overkill for simply searching a directory. `opendir`/`readdir` still has a purpose!

This program does a `chdir` to the specified directory so that there is no need to build the full path from the names generated by `readdir`.

The directory to search and the required prefix can be passed as command-line parameters and will default to `logs` and `A` if they are not supplied.

```
use strict;  
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($dir, $prefix) = @ARGV ? @ARGV : qw/ logs A /;
chdir $dir;

my @wanted = do {
  opendir(my $dh, '.');
  grep { -d and /^\Q$prefix/ } readdir $dh;
};

print "$_\n" for @wanted;
```